# Unable to bind JSON Array to ListBox in c# Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, json, listbox, windows-phone-8.1

Hi to all I have a Json

```
public class Contact
{
    public string contact_name_given { get; set; }
    public string contact_name_middle { get; set; }
    public string contact_name_family { get; set; }
    public List<object> contact_phones { get; set; }
    public List<object> contact_addresses { get; set; }
    public List<object> contact_notes { get; set; }
    public string contact_dialer { get; set; }
}
public class RootObject
{
    public string user_uuid { get; set; }
    public string add_date { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> contact { get; set; }
}
```

and i need to bind to a listbox: "contact_name_given" , "contact_name_family" and "contact_phones". I tried to do like this:

```
List<RootObject> des = DeserializeFromJson<List<RootObject>>(result);
for (int i =0; i< des.Count; i++)
PhoneList.ItemsSource = des[i].contact;
```

but this shows me only the last contact name, how can i show all the contacts in the ListBox ?
Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is the following.

In your main listbox's DataTemplate you should add 3 more listboxes in order to display your info, that's because the properties you want to bind are List.

```
<ListBox Name=“box”>
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
        <Listbox ItemSource = {Binding first_property_name_goes_here} >
            <Listbox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
        </Listbox.ItemTemplate>
        </Listbox>


        <Listbox ItemSource = {Binding second_property_name_goes_here} >
            <Listbox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
        </Listbox.ItemTemplate>
        </Listbox>

        <Listbox ItemSource = {Binding third_property_name_goes_here} >
            <Listbox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
        </Listbox.ItemTemplate>
        </Listbox>

</StackPanel>
</DateTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</Listbox
```

And for each nested listbox you'll define the datatemplate of how you want the items to display, and of course in each datatemplate you'll bind properties from the class in your List